# Set value through variable

Tags: python

How can i set value of referenced variable but not the variable?
Hard to explain, here is example:

```
Var = bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Forearm.L"].constraints["IK"].influence #I saved influence into Var
#influence of that bone is 0.5
Var = 1 #But it didn't set to actuall influence, its just set to Var in code memory
#influence of that bone still is 0.5 but Var is 1 now
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this variable?

Comment: @lemon just checkin value and then change it

Comment: This is Python question in fact. First line does not get `influence` but gets the value of it. You should get `c = bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Forearm.L"].constraints["IK"]` then `c.influence = 1`

Comment: @lemon oh wow, that WORKS. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to Blender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Python question in fact. First line does not get `influence` but gets the value of it.

You should get

```
c = bpy.context.object.pose.bones["Forearm.L"].constraints["IK"]
```

then

```
c.influence = 1
```

_ lemon

Comment: Nice : ) . Consider accepting your answer.